# How to redirect to a tab of a new page in Framework7?

Tags: tabs, html-framework-7

So lets say i have four images. I click on #3 and it should lead me to a page, where it opens tab #3 and so on. The problem is, the app does not know the classes beforehand. Only if i have opened the page before, it works correctly.

```
myApp.onPageInit('page-1 page-2', function (page) {
    $$('.show-tab-of-page2').on('click', function () {
        mainView.router.loadPage('page2.html');
        myApp.showTab('#tab-of-page-2');
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Create another onPageInit call for "page2". Once the user gets to page 2 it will open the tab.

```
myApp.onPageInit('page1', function (page) {
    $$('.show-tab-of-page2').on('click', function () {
        mainView.router.loadPage('page2.html');
    });
});

myApp.onPageInit('page2', function (page) {
            myApp.showTab('#tab-of-page-2');
    });
```

Comment: I tried that. Page Init calls that one tab, no matter what image i click because it init everytime that same tab.